# XMLSerializer InvalidOperationException when serializing protobuf

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, xmlserializer

I have the following protobuf messages defined:

```xml
message ClientMessage{
    oneof data{
        CheckAlive alive = 1;
        Login login = 2;
        SendMessage sendMessage = 3;
        Logout logout = 4;
    }
}
```

When I try to use `XmlSerializer` to serialize `ClientMessage` with i get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'To be XML serializable, types which inherit from IEnumerable must have an implementation of Add(System.Object) at all levels of their inheritance hierarchy. Google.Protobuf.ByteString does not implement Add(System.Object).'
```

Code used to serialize the object:

```cs
using (var stream = MemoryUtils.MemoryStreamManager.GetStream())
using (var xml = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        xs.Serialize(xml, item);

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true))
        {
             stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
             return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"When I try to use XmlSerializer to serialize ClientMessage"_ - why do you do that?

Comment: @CodeCaster i need to convert the message to an XML string

Comment: Why? And why are you using protobuf then?

Comment: @CodeCaster because wherever i am sending this to is expecting an xml string and protobuf makes it easier to handle things on my side prior to sending messages.

Comment: Yeah but protobuf classes are for serializing through protobuf, not XML. So create a separate class for XML serialization.

Comment: @CodeCaster i understand, i was just wondering why did it not work with this particular message, because it seems to work with other messages and everywhere else in the system where this method is used, it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out. The `SendMessage` message contained a `bytes` field which could not be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

In general, generated POCOs only work with the engine they are designed for. However! Protobuf-net is an alternative engine for protobuf that uses standard .NET idioms, and therefore *might work just fine*. You'd need to change your protobuf code to use the protobuf-net library, but it should be compatible.

The tooling to process .proto is available in many ways, most simply via https://protogen.marcgravell.com

Comment: Just to reiterate, you are suggesting I use Protobuf-net for serialization instead?

Comment: @julzzzz I'm saying that protobuf-net is a similar protobuf serializer which may, as a consequence of its design, be more friendly with other tools like `XmlSerializer`. So if your intent is to use both XML and protobuf with the same model, it might help you do that.